# responding to buttons inside gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, button, adapter

I have created a grid view with buttons inside.

But now the problem is that i don't understand for which click am i suppose to respond? The one on the grid view or the one on the button?

Moreover i have really no idea on how to set click listeners in the custom adapter class that i have created or should i set them in the main class.

I have tried googling but to no use. I would be really really thankful if someone helps me in figuring out this conceptual problem or at least point me towards a good resource. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set an onClickListener for each button.

Define these where you are defining your UI. Most of the time this is in your the `onCreate` method in your `activity`.

```
button1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        // do something
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        // do something
    }
});

button3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        // do something
    }
});

button4.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

---

> Moreover i have really no idea on how to set click listeners in the
>   custom adapter class that i have created or should i set them in the
>   main class.

Can you give more detail about your adapter?